# Print Field 'N' to End of Line

Tags: linux, unix, awk, cut, gawk

I would like to have help or direction on a problem I have in awk.

I have a tab-delimited file with more than 5 fields. I want to output the fields excluding the first 5 fields.

Could you please tell how to write an awk script to accomplish this task?

Best,
jianfeng.mao

Do Note the following kind comment:

There are many fields in my files. Different lines have a different number of fields. The number of fields per line is not standard.

Comment: do you have a standard set of fields? or do does the field count vary. For example sometimes 6 fields sometimes 10 fields?

Comment: Yes, there are many fields. Different file with different number of fields. I do not know how many of them.

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer that answered your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree with matchew's suggestion to use `cut`: it's the right tool for this job. But if this is just going to become a part of a larger `awk` script, here's how to do it:

```
awk -F "\t" '{ for (i=6; i<=NF; ++i) $(i-5) = $i; NF = NF-5; print; }
```

Comment: Dear user349433, I am now trying to learn from your awk script. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 5):

In my tab delimited file `temp.txt` it looks like the following

> field1    field2  field3  field4  field5  field6 
>   field1    field2  field3  field4  field5  field6 field7
>   field1    field2  field3  field4  field5  field6 field7 field 8

As per your update, I strongly recommend using `cut`:

```
cut -f6- temp.txt
```

will print field6 to end of line.

Note `-d` specifies the delimiter, but tab is the default delimiter. 
You can do this in `awk`, but I find `cut` to be simpler.

With `awk` it would look like this:

```
 awk '{print substr($0, index($0, $6))}' temp.txt
```

<strike>if my tab delimited file temp.txt looks like the following</strike>

> field1    field2  field3  field4  field5  field6 
>   field1    field2  field3  field4  field5  field6 field7
>   field1    field2  field3  field4  field5  field6 field7 field 8

```
awk -F"\t" '{print $6}' temp.txt
```

will print only the 6th field. if the delimiter is tab it will likely work without setting -F, but I like to set my field-separator when I can.

similarly so too would cut.

```
cut -f6 temp.txt
```

I have a hunch your question is a bit more complicated then this, so if you respond to my comment I can try and expand on my answer.

Comment: `cut` is great for simplicity, but does not handle inconsistent delimiters (mixture of different whitespaces). +1 for using `substr` in the `awk` solution.

Answer (score 2):

perl way?

```
perl -lane 'splice @F,0,5;print "@F"'
```

so,

```
echo 'field1 field2 field3 field4 field5 field6' | perl -lane 'splice @F,0,5;print "@F"'
```

will produce

```
field6
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -vFS='\t' -vOFS='\t' '{
  $1=$2=$3=$4=$5=""
  print substr($0,6) # delete leading tabs
}'
```

I use `-vFS='\t'` rather than `-F'\t'` because some implementations of awk (e.g. BusyBox's) don't honor C escapes in the latter construction.