# How would I split the following string in bash

Tags: string, bash, split

Suppose we have a string of the form

```
first;second;third;fourth
```

I would like to print

```
second;third;fourth
```

How would I do it?

Comment: Where is that string coming from? Is it stored in a variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading between the lines of your requirements, if you want to print everything after the first semicolon, I would use the POSIX standard `expr` utility.

```
expr "first;second;third;fourth" : '[^;]*;\(.*\)'
```

Comment: @ennuikiller: What exactly do you mean by cryptic? It was the most portable solution that I could think of at the time.

Answer (score 3):

Use parameter substitution (match beginning; delete shortest part):

```
str="first;second;third;fourth"

echo "${str#*;}"
```

Answer (score 3):

The `cut` command may do the trick very nicely:

```
echo "first;second;third;forth" | cut -d';' -f2-
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    $ v="first;second;third;fourth"
    $ echo ${v#first;}
    second;third;fourth
    $ q=${v#*;}
    $ echo $q
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "first;second;thrid;fourth" | awk -F";" '{print substr($0,index($0,$2))}'
```

A lot of these answers work, and I think `cut` may be the best solution, but its a slow night so I added another, print field 2 to end of the line.

Its very similar to a different question however:

[Print Field 'N' to End of Line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6307788/print-field-n-to-end-of-line/6307906#6307906)